# How to replace backward slash(\) with forward slash(/) in TCL script

Tags: tcl

I'm writing a TCL script and I would like to replace \ with /.

```
#File directory
set fDir "U:\scripts"
#Replacment of \ with / in the directory path using regular expression
regsub -all {\\} $fDir {/} fDir
tk_messageBox -message $fDir
```

I'm getting output as: 
    U:scripts

I would like have the output as:
    U:/scripts

Comment: You should not use string manipulation command to operate with the file name and path. It could generate many unexpected issues depends on OS specific. Instead you should use TCL commands like `file join`, `file separator`, `file nativename`, `file normalize` etc. These are implemented specially for platform independed manipulation with a file path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a single backslash, the interpreter tries to construct an escape sequence from it. When it fails, it just strips the backslash:

```
% set fDir "U:\scripts"
U:scripts
```

To get a string with a backslash in it, you need to either brace the string or escape the backslash:

```
% set fDir {U:\scripts}
U:\scripts
% set fDir U:\\scripts
U:\scripts
```

Then you can use your `regsub` invocation to change the backslashes to slashes. If you don’t feel it’s necessary to go the long route through a regular expression, you can use the dedicated command for it:

```
% set fDir [file normalize $fDir]
```

Documentation:

[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm)

[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Thank you.  It could be helpful for others if the last line is changed to  set fDir [file normalize $fDir].

Comment: I might've used `string map` instead of `regsub`, but that's otherwise perfect (and some versions of Tcl will internally optimise this case anyway).

Comment: @harishli2020: I believe you can make such edits yourself if you think they improve the answer.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#File directory
set fDir "U:\\scripts"
#Replacment of \ with / in the directory path using regular expression
regsub -all {\\} $fDir / fDir
puts $fDir
```

I tested on online [editor](http://rextester.com/l/tcl_online_compiler) and it worked

Result is

```
U:/scripts
```

Comment: Yes it works. But it needs an extra step to replace backslash in a long path with double backslashes.